# 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, osgeo4w, whitebox-tools

When I open the Windows 10 command line and write "java -version" at the cursor, the response is: *java version "1.8.0_391"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_391-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.391-b13, mixed mode)*

However, when I use the OSGeo4W Shell command line, and type "java -version", the response is: *'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

When I try to use the Whitebox Tools tools for rasters, this error message appears: *'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Process returned error code 1*

**How to fix this error?**

Answer (score 2):

In your OSGeo4W window, check the value of JAVA_HOME environmental variable. This example is from my computer:

```
C:\OSGeo4W>set java_home
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.21.9-hotspot\
```

Add `bin` at the end of the java directory and append that path into the OSGeo4W search path

```
C:\OSGeo4W>set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.21.9-hotspot\bin
```

Now java is found.

```
C:\OSGeo4W>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.21+9 (build 11.0.21+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.21+9 (build 11.0.21+9, mixed mode)
```

For making the change permanent edit the `o4w_env.bat` file that is located in the `[OSGEO4W_ROOT]/bin` directory. The line to edit is

```
set path=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%WINDIR%\system32;%WINDIR%;%WINDIR%\system32\WBem
```

Add your java bin directory at the end of the line.

After updating OSGeo4W with the installer program, check if the bat file has been overwritten.